# Whats a good way to implement an extended data structure in a pipeline pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, pipeline

I want to implement a pipeline pattern. That means i want to implement multiple stages working on a common job in a sequential manner. The stages themselves get a reference to the jobs data, and can modify this data:

```dart
class PipelineJob{
  final JobData data;
  final stages = [FirstStage(), SecodnStage()];
  run(){
    for(stage in stages){
      stage.run(data);
    }
  }
}

class PipelineStage{
  run(JobData data){
    // do something with data
  }  
}

class Pipeline{
  InputData input;
  OutputData result;
  start(InputData input){
    final job = PipelineJob.fromInput(input);
    job.run(); 
  }
}
```

So far, so good. But now i might have some data in the job, that is conditional on some type. And stages want to process this data differently depending on this type. Specifically, lets say, job data is structured in the following way:

```dart
class JobData {
  List<Info> infos;
}

class Info {
  DateTime time;
}

class ExtendedInfo extends Info {
  int count;
}
```

Depending on the type of info a stage mgith want to modify an `Info` object or might expect an `ExtendedInfo`, but might not want to change the type of the object. So i can check if an object is an ExtendedInfo with `is ExtendedInfo` and i can run the stage conditionally.

But for a general stage, that would process `Info` in general: How can i guarantee, that my stage will create `ExtendedInfo` objects, when my stage is trying to replace an existing `ExtendedInfo` object in the jobs `job.data.infos`?

1. Inheritance: One way would be to let the stage always check with `is ExtendedInfo` and create the appropiate type and then store it.

```dart
class Info{
  DateTime time;
  int? counter;
}

class ExtendedInfo extends Info {
  int count;
}

class JobData{
  List<Info> infos;
}

class FirstStage implements PipelineStage{
  run(JobData data){
    for(int i = 0; i<data.infos.length; i++){
      if(data.infos[i] is ExtendedInfo){
        data.infos[i] = processExtendedInfo(i);
      }
    }
  }

  ExtendedInfo processExtendedInfo(ExtendedInfo i){
    // process it, create and return result
  }  
}
```

2. Optional parameters: Another way, would be to merge `ExtendedInfo` and `Info` into one `Info` class with more optional fields:

```dart
class Info{
  DateTime time;
  int? counter;
}

class JobData{
  List<Info> infos;
}
```

that would give better type safety, but in general this practice would make null checks necessary every time one tries to use an extended info.

3. Extension class: I could move the "extension" of `Info` into an optional extension class

```dart
class Info{
  DateTime time;
}

class InfoExtension{
  int counter;
}

class JobData{
  List<Info> infos;
  List<InfoExtension?> infoExtensions;
}
```

this preserves type safety, requires handling the lists together doe, which is kinda awkward. One could easily forget to update `infoExtensions` alongside with `infos`.

What is a good approach?

Comment: "Best practice" is subjective and therefore not a good fit for the StackOverflow Q&A format. If you're looking for _advice_ you might consider a Java forum instead. Otherwise, can you ask a more specific question that can be answered objectively?

Comment: I know theres a "dont ask subjective questions" guideline. But basically, every question is subjective on some level. Same here, theres no point in rephrasing it imo. It is a question regarding a programming design pattern, regardless of the programming language (here dart). And every answer and necessarily every question regarding patterns will in some sort reference a "best practice" or a "recommended pattern", i dont see any way around it. many questions in "design patterns" start with "is it bad" or "is it a good approach" asking for opinions, and thats fine imo.

Comment: on second thought, i will rephrase it to 'What is a good approach?' to at least mitigate the subjection to what's 'best'.